# create a GUI for task scheduler using python script

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a script developed to create a task scheduler where it has 3 GUI buttons 'Add', 'Edit' and 'Remove' in the scheduler window. Clicking on 'Add' will open a task scheduler window where user can set the task,date,time and task name,etc.,after applying the settings and when clicked on 'ok', the GUI returns back to scheduler window updated with the set task name details of it in the list.Whereas 'Edit' window is used to edit the task scheduler selected from the list.I have class called 'class AddTask' which is the event created when clicked on 'Add' button.Similarly when clicked on 'Edit' i am  calling the same AddTask class by creating a object of it from which i call edit function.I want these 'AddTask' and 'EditTask' should be independent class and function as they are expected to.

I want the GUI for both Add and Edit button must be same but the functionality's should be different,for ADD it has to add the task and update it in the list in the scheduler whereas for EDIT it has to edit the task scheduler which is selected from the list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use an ObjectListView widget rather than a ListCtrl as I find ObjectListView to be easier to update. Either way, for the Add/Edit frame, you can just add an argument called "fields" or some such and set it to None.

```
class AddTask(wx.Frame):
    #------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, fields=None):
```

Then you can call it the normal way for Adding data. However, when you go to call it for Editing, you will pass a list (or a dict) of the values from the ListCtrl to fill in the fields in this frame. You'll need to add something like

```
if fields:
    # set the values of the widgets as necessary
    self.field.SetValue("Task Name")
```

Comment: How do i getitemlist and setitemlist in objectviewlist?? I need to set the list based on the values set from the Addtask frame!I tried with    self.list_ctrl.SetObjects(self.List) but did not work.

Comment: SetObjects takes a list of objects or dictionaries. Maybe this article will help you: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

Comment: we use 'self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index,taskname)' using wxListCtrl to update the list. I want the command similar to this to work with ObjectListView.

Comment: As the name implies, ObjectListView is based on using objects. Its API has similarities to the ListCtrl because it is a wrapper of the ListCtrl, however it is not one-for-one. You cannot use InsertStringItem unless you are going to add that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried

```
def UpdateList(self,task):
    run="Disabled"
    status="Not Scheduled"
    date=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    self.List=[{"taskname":"%s"%(task),"run":"%s"(run),"date":"%s"(date),"status":"%s"%(status)}]
    list1=self.listOlv.SetObjects(self.List)
```